# How to pass a dynamic amount of arguments to strings.xml?

Tags: android, string, android-resources

Passing one or two arguments to a string in strings.xml it's possible doing this:

```
<string name="test">%1$s from %2$s.</string>

context.getString(R.string.test, name, name2);
```

result:

> Pedro from Pablo.

The problem is that now I need to pass a dynamic amount of arguments, not knowing how much in each case, my idea is to get a result similar to this:

> Pedro from Pablo, Paco, Peco, Puco.

It is possible to do it with a XML trick? or the only way is to do it manually with Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is possible with Android resources, because the number of arguments to substitute is always fixed, they have a fixed position and there is nothing which could represent a repeating pattern. Only Java methods support an arbitrary number of arguments with `String...`, where the `...` means `varargs`.

String resources could only be used as far as defining the basic sentence and the repeating pattern, but gluing that together requires custom code - else it won't ever be a truly dynamic substitution.

[Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) explains it.

Answer (score -2):

You have to define it through Java only. if you know the no of dynamic content then you can define it in xml. according to your need. you have generate the second argument in loop separated by comma an then pass it to xml.

Comment: i don't know the amount of arguments, as described in question

Comment: How do you get the second argument? .it must from server or  from local right?.

Comment: it's just a test... for posting the question